# How to get Google Chrome to expand the hidden "[object Object]" data to record in the "chrome_debug.log"?

Tags: google-chrome, logging, html, javascript, console

In Chrome, I can observe a site's JavaScript/data by right clicking on the page and selecting "Inspect", and then I click the "Console" tab, and scroll down a bit in a particular site. I might see something like this:

[image: Inspect console example]

I wanted to find a way to record this JavaScript info to a log, and sure enough, there's a way to achieve this. Right click on the Chrome shortcut, and set the "Target" to the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --enable-logging --v=1
```

Chrome then proceeds to update a log file updated at:

```
C:/Users/[USERNAME]/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/chrome_debug.log
```

Now here's the problem. Inside that log, I see:

```
[53942:74227:4921/203256.143:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "%c Game %c AppInsights.trackEvent: CaseD background: #404040; color: white; display: block; font-weight: bold; background: #FFFFFF; color: #8A8A8A; display: block; [object Object]", source: https://examplesite.com/longtail.js (3)
```

The `[object Object]` bit is the part that is hiding the info given in the image above. What flag can I add to the Chrome shortcut target so that `[object Object]` expands to the info shown in the image? For example, I want the chrome_debug.log file to also record the "BoxIndex" and "Cid" strings with the values "1" and "K948".

I tried to increase the verbosity to 3 (and even 8) with the Target addition `--v=3`, but to no avail.

I suspect the answer to my question is within this giant page full of [command line switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). However, there are too many to check through manually. Does anyone know what I need to add to the Chrome shortcut Target to achieve what I want?

Comment: The relevant switch might be `--log-level` : "Sets the minimum log level. Valid values are from 0 to 3: INFO = 0, WARNING = 1, LOG_ERROR = 2, LOG_FATAL = 3".

Comment: @harrymc: Thanks, tried each of those numbers for that flag, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't seem to have an automatic method for doing so.
It's perhaps intentional, as an object can be enormous - up to an entire
HTML page.

You will need to print the object yourself using JavaScript.
You could modify the target site JavaScript code by using an extension
such as Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey. You could also add your own code
using the Developer tools (with some limitations).

For JavaScript ideas, see the post
[console.log(result) returns [object Object]. How do I get result.name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336663/console-logresult-returns-object-object-how-do-i-get-result-name).

Comment: Just made it - 9 minutes to the bounty expiry! I might see if I can experiment in that direction - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `console.log(AppInsights.trackEvent)`, try

```
console.log(...Object.entries(AppInsights.trackEvent).flat())
```

It turns

```
console.log({
  BoxIndex: "1",
  cid: "K948",
  CorrelationID: "4525d95d-e4dc-804e-bff3-4b6ba43f531c"
  ...
})
```

into

```
console.log("BoxIndex", "1", "cid", "K948", "CorrelationID", "452...)
```

and thus your info [should](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39099353) be visible in the log.

Comment: The log is saved automatically by Chrome and updated live in the file named "chrome_debug.log". Not sure how I can use your technique to get this automated? I'm not typing anything into the console itself, since the file needs to be updated continuously and automatically as a log.